# With and without the quantifier {1} has same effect?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any difference between the regular expressions:-

> /^[1-9][0-9]+$/

and

> /^[1-9]{1}[0-9]+$/

They both seem to give the same result. Which convention is better,because in many examples I can see the use of {1}, but feel it is quite useless, am I right?

Comment: The `{1}` quantifier is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: @Pointy I think in any case, {n} is meaningless when n=1, am I right?

Comment: I'm certainly having a hard time thinking of a case where it actually makes a difference in the meaning of the regex.

Comment: There is no such case, it is the same.

Comment: From the [`regex` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): *Using `{1}` as a single-repetition quantifier is harmless, but very often an indication of inexperience and/or confusion.*

Comment: As for confusion: Some people seem to think that by adding a `{1}`, the regex engine would interpret it as "match only if there is exactly one instance", so that `a{1}` would match `a` but not `aa`, which is not the case, of course.